# LinkedIn follow company button showing blank page

Tags: javascript, html, css, linkedin-api

I copied the code from [this link](https://developer.linkedin.com/plugins/follow-company) by giving company name and clicking the **Get Code** button. It generated the code given below

```
<script src="//platform.linkedin.com/in.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script type="IN/FollowCompany" data-id="361557" data-counter="right"></script>
```

I pasted this code in  tag of a html file and then run the html file in Chrome, Firefox and IE, but all browser gave a blank page as output.

Then I paste those script n the  tag but the output remains same.

How should I create the html file, so that it could generate the **inFollow** button.

Please help me.

Comment: can you view the source of in.js file in your html

Comment: @refhat in.js is not my script file. Its the linkedin file. you can see the source code by selecting the complete url associated with it and paste it in address bar of any browser. Just use the url platform.linkedin.com/in.js

Comment: I think problem is on Linkedin side. I had this script for almost one year, and it worked. Few days ago I saw that button is oppening about:blank page.

Comment: Problem can be reproduced even on generator page.

Comment: @AndrewLuca Just so you know, you only need to type your message once... Not on every post on the page.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well it appears that you are just invoking the JavaScript. You must place the JavaScript into an HTML Document and then have an element that corresponds with that script.

Remember you also have to have a full structured HTML Document before you can just place Script tags into it, you need html, body, head, tags, etc.

Try creating an HTML Document and placing this within the .html file.

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>Untitled Document</title>
</head>

<body>

<script src="//platform.linkedin.com/in.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script type="IN/FollowCompany" data-id="361557" data-counter="right"></script>

</body>
</html>
```

Tips to remember:

- A lot of scripts require an element to correspond with.
- You may    either place the script within the script tags in the body
  tags or    the head tags, depending on if you may or may not be
  selecting an    element on the page.
- Each HTML document requires the correct mark-up    before a browser
  can render it.

Hope this helps!

**EDIT:**
Just upload it to a server, once you do that, it will work. I cannot explain why though.

Comment: Did you tried this? Is it working for you? Actually already I have tried this before asking the question but I got the same blank page.

Comment: @ChandraSekhar: I did try the above, and I uploaded it to a server. And once I ran the document via a browser while it was placed on a server it worked perfectly fine for me. I saw the button and everything.

Comment: I am running it just through a local file. Then why it is not working?

Comment: @chandraSekhar: I cannot give you a great explanation regarding why it does not work fully when it is being run locally, but I do know that some scripts do this.

Comment: Thanks dear its working through server. If you know the reason behind not running locally, please let me know.

Comment: @ChandraSekhar: You are very welcome! I haven't figured this one out yet. But maybe, just maybe, it could be Server-Side Script driven... Hence it may send Server-Side Requests via AJAX. Whom knows.

Comment: Aaron I think you are right. I ran it through tomcat server and it works for me.

Comment: I think problem is on Linkedin side. I had this script for almost one year, and it worked. Few days ago I saw that button is oppening about:blank page.

Comment: Problem can be reproduced even on generator page.

Answer (score 1):

It is not working locally because it is using protocol relative URL. If you change `src="//platform.linkedin.com/in.js"` to `src="https://platform.linkedin.com/in.js"` it will work.

Comment: I think problem is on Linkedin side. I had this script for almost one year, and it worked. Few days ago I saw that button is oppening about:blank page. I use it on live site.

Comment: Problem can be reproduced even on generator page.