# Issues with LinkedIn follow Button

Tags: linkedin-api

I want to use linkedIn follow button for evey user like User provide his profile url and we create a follow button with the help of that url . I have get the follow button code from LinkedIn :

```
<script src="//platform.linkedin.com/in.js" type="text/javascript">
  lang: en_US
</script>
<script type="IN/FollowCompany" data-id="test" data-counter="right"></script>
```

we get the company / username from url and replace data-id with that . But this code doesn't show any follow button at front end. Is there any html code I have to use for that (But linkedIn doesn't provide that code). So Please How I can show follow button at front end.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

you don't need any HTML code for that , just placed the js code where you want to show follow button . you can get better idea from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11312560/linkedin-follow-company-button-showing-blank-page)

Answer (score 0):

You're not using an actual id for company in the script: `data-id="test"`.

You need to use a real id.

Select yours from the dropdown in the tool you used to create the button:[image]