# LinkedIn Company Follow Button Not Working

Tags: linkedin-api

Does anybody have an update on why LinkedIn company page follow button doesn't work anymore?

I generated the code at - `https://developer.linkedin.com/plugins/follow-company`

Code:

```
<script src="//platform.linkedin.com/in.js" type="text/javascript"> lang: en_US</script>
<script type="IN/FollowCompany" data-id="2656413"></script>
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: could you check inside the developer console what the errors are ? because there has to be reason it is not working.

Comment: Hi @LarsHendriks I don't see any error in the console. Also, same happen on the LinkedIn site itself. Please check https://developer.linkedin.com/plugins/follow-company 
and our site https://staging.suntuitiveglass.com/dynamic-visible-light-range/

Answer (score 3):

I found solution recently, maybe will work for someone.

```
<p>
    <iframe 
        id="iframeOne"
        src="https://www.linkedin.com/pages-extensions/FollowCompany?id=1337&amp;
            counter=top&amp;
        class="IN-widget IN-widget--iframe" 
        scrolling="no" 
        allowtransparency="true" 
        frameborder="0" 
        border="0" 
        width="1" 
        height="1" 
        style="vertical-align: bottom; width: 160px; height: 45px;">
    </iframe>
</p>
```

Comment: It simply worked!

Comment: Where did you get this snippet from?

Comment: Found this very useful for adding the LinkedIn follow using NextJS, as their <Script /> component seemed to render it twice and at the bottom of the doc. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

well when i look at the linkedin website i see the following errors :

[error linkedin](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Gc378.jpg)

so obviously there is something wrong with the code. and because you only load 2 script in. but befor you do that try this :

```
<script src="//platform.linkedin.com/in.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script type="IN/FollowCompany" data-id="accountID" data-counter="none"></script>
```

this is how used to do it, i dont see much of difference but you could try to add a data-counter and remove the language.

Comment: does this work for you? It is still not working. I just tried - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11312560/linkedin-follow-company-button-showing-blank-page this doesn't work either.

Comment: well i do not use it anymore, i just pulled up an old piece of code from a project some months/years ago